# Visual Studio 2013 - HTML elements with multiple classes and fighting with intellisense

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to edit HTML and have an annoying quirk that I cannot seem to find any answers online. And it seems to be simple.

Let's say I'm creating a `<div />` with CSS classes, `btn` and `btn-xs`. Unfortunately, Intellisense tries to be too smart and incurrs me EXTRA keystrokes, rather than less. I start typing:

```
<div class="btn
```

and we're good so far. At this point, I would like to continue to type the next class. But if I hit the spacebar, this happens:

```
<div class="btn" |
```

Where the | represents the cursor. Why does this happen? Can I turn it off?  The closest solutions I've found are either:

- Hit ESCAPE after each class. This closes the Intellisense popup and let's me type normally. Since ESCAPE is a pretty remote key, and I often have many classes to add to an element, I'd rather not make the 5-fret-stretch.
- I could also just press the arrow-left key to move over. Again, this is a remote key, and I again find myself reaching for the stars with my pinky.

So what's a guy to do? Sure this is a minor irritant, but the whole reason I signed up for this Intellisense train is to use less keystrokes, not more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Menu: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Advanced

Change value for "Insert attribute value quotes: to `False`.

[image]

Comment: Negative. Which is surprising considering I fully expected to tick that value and have it work. Didn't work before or after a VS restart.  Looks like that may be the right section of VS to look around though.

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2013.

Comment: I understand. I fully expect it to work.  Let me get some screens to show what I'm dealing with.

Comment: It works! but not with existing tags. If the closing double quotes already exist the original behavior persists. Thanks for that one!